# How can I convert Windows shortcut files to regular files, but keep the short cut name?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a million photos in my directory tree of photos.  Recently, I created another directory of shortcuts to select a set of photos I want to use.  I used special shortcut filenames setup to sort the photos in the order I want.

The problem is, when I import the directory of photo shortcuts into Adobe Lightroom, Lightroom uses the underlying filenames, not the shortcut names.  This loses the shortcut names I wanted to sort by.

I found this Powershell program to convert shortcuts to actual files, but it also uses the underlying filenames, not the shortcut names, when writing to the destination:

```
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
# Source directory to copy from
$LinksFolder = 'D:\ShortcutFolder'
# Destination USB drive
$ExtDrive = 'E:'
# "fullname" gets the underlying filename, not the shortcut name
gci $LinksFolder *.lnk -recurse | select -expand fullname | Foreach{
       $Source = ($wshShell.CreateShortcut($_)).TargetPath
       $Destination = (split-path $_ ).Replace($LinksFolder, $ExtDrive)
       # Add -whatif to this to test
       Copy-Item $Source $Destination 
}
```

How can I convert shortcut files to actual files containing the content of the target of the shortcut, but using the shortcut filename for the written file?

Thanks in advance
Ben

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with the `md $Destination` command. Do you want all the photos to end up in your `$LinksFolder`, or do you want to preserve some part of the  `$Source` image's folder?

Comment: Ignore the "md $Destination".  I wasn't even using that.  I've removed it from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the shortcut's `$_.Name` in the `$Destination`, but keep the `$Source` file's extension:

```
$linksFolder = 'D:\ShortcutFolder'
$DestFolder = 'D:\ShortcutFolder' #Do you want all the photos to end in the links folder?
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell

gci $LinksFolder '*.lnk' -recurse | Foreach{
       $Source = Get-item ($wshShell.CreateShortcut($_.FullName)).TargetPath

       #change the extension to match source. Hopefully there's no extra '.lnk' in the name
       $Destination = Join-Path $DestFolder $_.Name.Replace('.lnk',$Source.Extension) 
       Copy-Item $Source $Destination -WhatIf #Take off -Whatif when you like the results
}
```

Comment: That worked!! (with slight modifications)  You are a scholar and a gentleman!  My files had names looking like  "2021_02_IMG_6299.jpg - Shortcut.lnk"  . I had to change to assign to $Destination line to the following:
$Destination = Join-Path $DestFolder $_.Name.Replace(' - Shortcut.lnk','')

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I had to make slight modifications to Rich's excellent answer as follows:

```
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$LinksFolder = 'D:\pictures'
# Dest is my USB thumbdrive
$DestFolder = 'L:'   
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
# my source files look like "2021_02_IMG_6299.jpg - Shortcut.lnk"
gci $LinksFolder '*.lnk' -recurse | Foreach{
       $Source = Get-item ($wshShell.CreateShortcut($_.FullName)).TargetPath
       #change the extension to match source. Hopefully there's no extra '.lnk' in the name
       $Destination = Join-Path $DestFolder $_.Name.Replace(' - Shortcut.lnk','') # changed Replace
       Copy-Item $Source $Destination -WhatIf     #Take off -Whatif when you like the results
}
```